# org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, hbase, hdfs

I'm working on a cluster with hbase.

One node crashed couple days ago. I restarted the cluster; since that time, the root region is in transition despite all my efforts.

> 70236052  -ROOT-,,0.70236052 state=CLOSING, ts=Wed Apr 10 15:06:04 CEST
>   2013 (417729s ago), server=NODE09...

I tried to :

- restart HBase
- remove the service and re-install it
- revome the service and install the master onto another node
- install 2 different Hbase
- format the HDFS namenode
- deleting the HBase file from HDFS system

It still can find this region in transition.

- I tried to access to the .META. table :

> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for
>    after 7 tries
>
> I attempted to use the command /bin/hbase hbck :
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for
>   after 10 tries.
>
> I'm out of ideas for solving this issue.

Does someone have any suggestions?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the time on the node where the problematic regionserver is on is not synchronized with the rest of the cluster. check that NTP is configured correctly.

In any event check the log of the problematic regionserver